# JavaScript find next coming date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

JavaScript find next coming date.need to find which date is coming next;

I have two date (firstdate) and (secondDate).I want to compare these dates with current date and find which date is next date.

```
data is like this;
var firstdate = 1;
var secondDate = 15;
var currentDate = new Date();
```

Comment: Have you tried `.isAfter()` method of MomentJS

Comment: yes i was tried but i can't find result that i was expect.

Answer (score 0):

If your data only have "Date" but not the month and year, compare those dates with `currentDate.getDate();`